# Syntax error saving fields to a CSV file

Tags: visualforce, community

Im Trying to write a button that triggers the following code or page:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Inquery__c" recordSetVar="accvar" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" >
"First Name","Last Name","Email","Qualification"
<apex:repeat value="{!accvar}" var="a">
<apex:outputText rendered="!NOT({!a.Downloaded__c})">
      {!a.First_Name__c}, {!a.Last_Name__c}, {!a.Email__c}, {!a.Quilification__c}
</apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

All this is suppose to do, is save the a.First_Name__c, a.Last_Name_*c, a.Email*_c, a.Quilification__c Fields to a CSV File,

IF the a.Downloaded__c CHECK box is checked( i.e. TRUE).

But the code above gives me a Syntax error,

Does anyone know what wrong with the code,

Thanks

Comment: Is the above sytax even compiling for you :/

Comment: With help ive changed it to the code above

Comment: Looks like you changed the code. Is it working for you now? Best practice is to leave the question as is and mark the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing:

```
rendered="!NOT({!a.Downloaded__c})"
```

to:

```
rendered="{!NOT(a.Downloaded__c)}"
```

Comment: That magically worked

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the `repeat` seems a bit odd to me.

Try switching it to a [outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) using the rendered attribute to toggle the display.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accvar}" var="a">
    <apex:outputText value="{0},{1},{2},{3}" rendered="{!a.Downloaded__c}">
        <apex:param value="{!a.First_Name__c}" />
        <apex:param value="{!a.Last_Name__c}" />
        <apex:param value="{!a.Email__c}" />
        <apex:param value="{!a.Quilification__c}" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

**UPDATE: To reverse the logic of the rendered attribute**

You can negate the rendered logic by putting a `!` within the visualforce expression syntax.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!accvar}" var="a">
    <apex:outputText value="{0},{1},{2},{3}" rendered="{! !a.Downloaded__c}">
        <apex:param value="{!a.First_Name__c}" />
        <apex:param value="{!a.Last_Name__c}" />
        <apex:param value="{!a.Email__c}" />
        <apex:param value="{!a.Quilification__c}" />
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I use the repeat command to download the fields to a CSV file,

Comment: That was my understanding from your example. Is this working for you now or are you still getting a syntax error? If you are getting a syntax error, please include the details in your question.

Comment: Well basically the code above does not work when I have the Downloaded__c field unchecked. The only way I can get it to work, is to remove NOT and use the code in the opposite manner, hence save the fields when Downloaded__c is checked! so why doesn't NOT work?

Comment: The logic needs to be within the visualforce expression syntax `{! expression}`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

I modified the original code to the following:

**UPDATE:**

```
 <apex:page standardController="Inquery__c" recordSetVar="accvar" contentType="text/csv#filename.csv" >
    "First Name","Last Name","Email","Qualification"
    <apex:repeat value="{!accvar}" var="a">
          {!IF(a.Downloaded__c == TRUE,a.First_Name__c, null)}, {!IF(a.Downloaded__c == TRUE,a.Last_Name__c, null)},{!IF(a.Downloaded__c == TRUE,a.Email__c, null)}, {!IF(a.Downloaded__c == TRUE,a.Quilification__c, null)}
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: I cant get that to work for me

Comment: I used account let me modify it for your code.

Comment: It give me the following error: Error: Download_Test line 1, column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog

Comment: Where are you pasting the page, are you pasting in the VF page area when you are creating the page?

Comment: yes I am, is that wrong?

Comment: can you get on chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9236/discussion-between-rao-and-user2333346)